# Where can I find Derekh Hatzala by Shlomo Helbrans?

Tags: product-recommendation, jewish-books

Where can I find Derekh Hatzala by Shlomo Helbrans. It is the main book of the Lev Tahor founder.

Comment: Do you have publisher's information, topical inofrmation, or biological information of the authors to [edit] into the question? Doing so may help someone find this book.

Comment: It isn't the main book of the Lev Tahor founder, rather [Ohr Havaya](http://levtahor.ca/148814931512-1492149314971492.html) is.

Comment: Is this on topic to Judaism Stack Exchange?

Answer (score 2):

[You can download it over here](http://levtahor.ca/149115121498-1492151015001492.html).

Comment: Hopefully you didn't just contribute to sucking someone into a cult. I'd recommend that you delete the answer while you still can, as the maximum amount of good it can do is help people find this book. The worst thing it could do is send people towards cults. That just my personal inclination.

Comment: Interesting background: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shlomo_Helbrans - see also under Lev Tahor in same link - I now understand what mevaqesh meant